# Problema ao calcular a quantidade de combustível com Javascript

Tags: javascript

> Chico Bento possui um carro que faz, em média, 12 km com um litro de
> gasolina. Ele realizou uma viagem com seu carro e está interessado em
> saber quantos litros de combustível o carro consumiu. Para tal, ele
> dispõe de duas informações: o tempo gasto dirigindo e a velocidade
> média do carro. Escreva um algoritmo para calcular quantos litros de
> combustível o carro de Chico Bento consumiu.

Código:

```
<script>
    // 12km = 1L de gasolina
    // O tempo gasto dirigido e a velocidade média do carro
    // velocidade media = D / T
    var distancia = parseFloat(prompt("Qual foi a distância percorrida ? ")); // 400KM
    var tempoGasto = parseFloat(prompt("Qual foi o tempo gasto da viagem ? ")); // 50 horas
    var vlcMedia = distancia / tempoGasto; // 200/30 = 8KM por hora
    var gasolina = 0;
    document.write("A distância percorrida foi: " + distancia + "km/h <br/>");
    document.write("O tempo gasto foi: " + tempoGasto + "hr/s <br/>");
    document.write("A velocidade média foi de: " + vlcMedia.toFixed(2) + "km/h <br/>");
    for(contador = 1; contador < vlcMedia; contador++){
        gasolina+=vlcMedia;
        document.write("Na " + contador + " hora de viagem, Chico Bento gastou " + gasolina.toFixed(2) + "L<br/>");
    }

</script>
```

Tentei encontrar pesquisas no [Google](https://www.google.com.br/) onde informa a resposta para comparar o que estava errado no meu código, porém não achei nada semelhante.
Sabendo que 12km = 1L de gasolina, como posso colocar isso no meu código? Pois pensei em fazer algo como `if` ou `while`.

A saída do meu código é esse:

> A distância percorrida foi: 500km/h
>
> O tempo gasto foi: 30hr/s
>
> A velocidade média foi de: 16.67km/h
>
> Na 1 hora de viagem, Chico Bento gastou 16.67L
>
> Na 2 hora de viagem, Chico Bento gastou 33.33L
>
> > . . .
>
> Na 16 hora de viagem, Chico Bento gastou 266.67L

Referência: [EscolaKids](https://escolakids.uol.com.br/matematica/velocidade-de-um-veiculo.htm), [UFRN](https://www.dimap.ufrn.br/%7Erichard/pubs/dim0320/readings/dim0320.pdf)

Comment: Se é 1L para cada 12Km e você definir a distancia como 500Km não bastaria dividir 500 por 12? `var litrosTotais = 500 / 12; // resultado: 41.66666`? Ou estou enganado? Como o resultado pode ser quebrado você pode usar `litrosTotais.toFixed(2)`. Isso eu assumi pelo enunciado da pergunta, eu entendi que seu código fala de litros gasto em cada hora especifica, mas me parece diferente do enunciado.

Comment: Está certo @GuilhermeNascimento, houve uma falha de interpretação de texto da minha parte sobre o enunciado.